# Error: "Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'Bool'"?

Tags: xcode, swift3, immutability, sender

How do I fix this? I'm a new coder. Thank you

I get the follow error:

> "Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'Bool'"

When I try to set the "isSelected" to `false` and `true`

```
@IBAction func onFilter(_ sender: Any) {

    if ((sender as AnyObject).isSelected == true) {

        hideSecondaryMenu()
        (sender as AnyObject).isSelected = false

    } else {

        showSecondaryMenu()
        (sender as AnyObject).isSelected = true

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because when you are converting sender to `AnyObject` you are getting `immutable` type object so you cannot update its properties, The best option to solved your problem is to change your sender declaration from `Any` to actual `UIControl` means if it is button then `UIButton`.

```
@IBAction func onFilter(_ sender: UIButton) {
    hideSecondaryMenu()
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
}
```

If you want to still use `Any` then convert sender to actual `UIControl` that it is belong to.

```
@IBAction func onFilter(_ sender: Any) {
    if sender is UIButton {
         let btn = sender as! UIButton
         hideSecondaryMenu()
         btn.isSelected = !btn.isSelected
    }
}
```