# Cannot assign to immutable expression of type ... but with protocols

Tags: swift, protocols

I know there are lots of questions starting like that. However, here's my code snippet:

```
protocol AProt { var a:Int { get set } }
protocol BProt { var b:Int { get set } }
protocol CProt { var c:Int { get set } }
class A:AProt, CProt { var a = 1;  var c = 3 }
class B:BProt, CProt { var b = 2; var c = 30 }

var a = A()
var b = B()
var c = a as CProt // works
c.c = 123
a = c as! A
print (a.c)
(a as CProt).c = 999 // throws error
print (a.c)
```

Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40880694/error-cannot-assign-to-immutable-expression-of-type-bool) it tells that the `(...as...)` makes the expression immutable. But ...

while the `(a as CProt).c = 999` fails with above error message, the work around with the `var c = a as CProt` works. I'd regard this as simple compiler bug, but I wanted to know whether there's something that could be done here (like adding a secret key word).

Comment: What is the reason for the `as CProt` cast if you can simply assign `a.c = 999` ?

Comment: @MartinR Well, it's a shrunken example and the whole context would blow the question. Maybe I have to rethink and enter the whole thing from the backdoor once again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't a compiler bug. `CProt` can be a value type. Consider this code:

```
protocol CProt { var c:Int { get set } }
struct A: CProt { var a = 1;  var c = 3 } // Note this is a struct
var a = A()  // It's mutable
let c = a as CProt  // But this one isn't
c.c = 999  // So no surprise this fails
```

Would you expect this to work? It shouldn't, since `c` is an immutable struct. This is the same thing you're writing in `(a as CProt).c = 999`.

The problem is you expect `CProt` to be a reference type. If you need that, then say so:

```
protocol CProt:class { var c:Int { get set } } // Note the addition of :class
class A: CProt { var a = 1;  var c = 3 }
let a = A()
(a as CProt).c = 999 // Success
```

Comment: Hi @Rob, this was my first thaught, but think of the following: If a were a struct, then `var c = a as CProt` creates a _copy_. So in case of `(a as CProt)`, this _could_ also create a copy, so no problem in assigning anthing to that copy. I know it's not the way they implemented it in swift, by why didn'nt they? Or am missing something here?

Comment: If `(a as CProt)` created a mutable copy, it would be useless since it would immediately be destroyed. That would be very confusing and bug prone. It's ok to create an immutable copy (and it does), but if you changed it and your changes were immediately lost that's the same as not changing it.

Comment: When I say "(and it does)," I mean "it is equivalent to creating an immutable copy." It may or may not actually copy any data. But you have to think of it as effectively creating a new value.

Comment: Ah! The `:class` is the secret sauce. Thanks for that!

Comment: Sorry I buried the lede there. Edited to make more clear.